# In which Control you can use Site Map

Tags: asp.net

i want to know in site navigation which contol can be used?
i just know we can use treeview but i want more control that work with Site Map!
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Dynamic menus
- TreeViews
- Site Map Path

Have a look at this info.

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp

Comment: does that mean this is not a real answer then?